# Matplotlib bar graph axes values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to have a bar graph showing x values ranging from 0-9.
The bars should have the same space, and the problem I'm having is fitting the 10 values together while all have the same area space for bars.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
results_plot = plt.subplot2grid((10, 6), (0,0), colspan=8, rowspan=2)
results_plot.set_title("Results")

res_x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
res_y = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

rects = plt.bar(res_x, res_y, color='b')
results_plot.set_xbound(lower=0.0, upper=9.0)
results_plot.set_ybound(lower=0.0, upper=100.0)


results_plot2 = plt.subplot2grid((10, 6), (3,0), colspan=8, rowspan=2)
results_plot2.set_title("Results 2")

res_x2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
res_y2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

rects2 = plt.bar(res_x2, res_y2, color='b')
results_plot2.set_xbound(lower=-.5, upper=9.5)
results_plot2.set_ybound(lower=0.0, upper=100.0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

So in short I want to see all the x values on the axes (like in figure 1) with each having the same bar space (figure 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want a tick below each bar, you can set the `xticks` directly using your `res_x`. Add:

```
results_plot2.set_xticks(res_x)
```

[image]

Comment: just what I was looking for, ty.